# font awesome hover color margin turns black

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm a beginner trying out some things on rails as I work through Michael Hartl's tutorial. I am trying to have my social media buttons change color upon hover, but I see the change of color in two stages: when the pointer is within the 'radius' of the font awesome button, it turns black; then when the pointer is right over the button itself it shows the color I intend. How could I make the button change color without first turning black?

After some searches, I've only found posts pertaining to changing the font awesome color upon hover, but I haven't found anything pertaining to this black-radius hover color change. All help is well received.

Thanks!

My footer html, where I placed the buttons:

```
<footer class="footer">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://twitter.com/twitteraccount" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-twitter" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/facebookaccount" class="btn btn-social-icon btn-facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</footer>
```

The CSS:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";


/* universal */

body {
  padding-top: 60px;
  background-color: #4B088A;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.center h1 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* header */

#logo {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font-size: 1.7em;
  color: #9400D3;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  padding-top: 9px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#logo:hover {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  color: #fff;
}

footer a {
  color: #fff;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: #222;
}

footer small {
  text-align: center;
}

footer ul {
  float: right;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.2em
}

footer ul li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.gap-right {
  margin-right: 10px; 
}

.fa:hover {
    color: #BCA9F5;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate the effect you're experiencing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into this issue because the `:hover` property is being defined first on `.footer a`, then on the `.fa` class, which will only happen when you hover on the icon. Also, bootstrap's `.btn` class will apply its hover style to the link, which is why you're getting that two-stage hover behavior, so you need to override that as well.

Remove:

```
.fa:hover {
    color: #BCA9F5;
}
```

Change:

```
footer a:hover {
  color: #BCA9F5;
}

footer .btn:hover {
   color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The change takes care of the two-stage hover, but now it only turns black (not the lighter color). Any ideas as to why that is?

Comment: It looks like bootstrap's .btn class is causing the behavior. I edited the answer to override the default hover color in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you! setting both to the same color (including the .btn class) solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

this CSS code is the problem, the link changes color once you hover it, then when you reach the fontawesome icon, the next rule is enforced.

`footer a:hover {
  color: #222;
}`